# Why can't a string be nil in Go?

Tags: go, variable-assignment

The program [available on The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2gLydmLeHf) reads

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var name string = nil
    fmt.Println(name)
}
```

and yields an error

```
prog.go:6: cannot use nil as type string in assignment
```

I understand [`""` is the "zero value" for strings](https://tour.golang.org/basics/12). I don't understand why I cannot assign `nil` to my `string`.

Comment: You can't assign `nil` to `int`s either.  Why does this surprise you for strings?

Comment: By preventing nil assignment to strings the language eliminates a class of errors. Note [string pointers](https://dhdersch.github.io/golang/2016/01/23/golang-when-to-use-string-pointers.html) can be assigned nil.

Comment: Not sure why this got down voted.  Seems like a pretty legitimate question to me

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**The simple answer is that `nil` is not defined to be a valid value for type `string` in the [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec).**

...but maybe you want a longer answer?

`nil` is the zero value for pointers, interfaces, channels, slices, maps and function types, and it represents an *uninitialized* state.

Consider the following variable declarations:

```
var a *SomeType
var b interface{}
var c func()
```

It seems natural that all these variables would have a value that represents uninitialized state. `a` has been declared as a pointer, but what would it point to, when we haven't yet pointed it at anything? `nil` is an obvious zero value for these types.

As for channels, slices and maps, their zero value is `nil` for the simple reason that their *implementation* is such that they must be explicitly initialized before they can be used. This is mostly for performance reasons, these types are all represented internally as more or less complex data structures, and initializing them is not free.

However, a `string` doesn't require initialization, and it seems natural that the default, zero value for a new string variable would be an empty string, `""`. Therefore there's simply no reason for `nil` to be a valid string value, and adding it to the specification would only make the language more complicated and much more cumbersome to work with.

Furthermore, what would `nil` of type `string` *represent*? An empty string? We already have that. An uninitialized string? There's no such thing.

Comment: Tip: If dealing with optional parameters - you can however, pass a pointer to your string, and pointers can be nil :) (You can also use an empty string.)

Comment: “_No_ _string_.”

Answer (score 13):

In go `string` is a data type and not a pointer to an array as in C/C++. As such you can't assign it to nil.

Answer (score 8):

Because Golang `string` is a read-only slices of bytes.

However, a pointer to a string (*string) can be nil:

```
var s *string
s = nil
readonly := "readonly"
s = &readonly
dereference := *s
```

https://dhdersch.github.io/golang/2016/01/23/golang-when-to-use-string-pointers.html

Answer (score 1):

Aedolon made some good points, but to go further, in other languages strings are convenient ways of representing arrays of bytes as characters. We need to do this a lot, so this specific use case of an array gets a lot of language support to make it easier to use. However, at the heart of the matter, you are working with an array, which is often able to be null in a language because it is a reference type. That is, the string isn't really null, the pointer to the array is null. Because many languages conflate these two things, programmers are used to having to check if a string is null before using it.

Go doesn't do this. A string cannot be nil, because the data structure in go doesn't allow it. You can have a pointer to a byte array holding character representations in go be null, but that isn't a string.